# Multi step modal - with progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build a popup for on-boarding wizard on my website. 
I'd like to refine it a bit more but I'm encountering problems of how to move forward.

Problem:

- I'd like the popup to appear on page load (and only for first time
  visit)
- I'd like the progress bar to be active along with the user,    so if
  they are on first step - 1 will be highlighted and so on

  ```
  <div id="sampleModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myTitle" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true" class="visible-xs">&times;</span>

                  </button>
                   <h4 class="modal-title" id="myTitle">Modal Title</h4>

              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  <div id="step1"> <span>Do something for Step 1</span>

                      <input type="textbox" />
                      <button id="btnEndStep1">NEXT STEP</button>
                  </div>
                  <div id="step2" class="hideMe"> <span>Now select something for Step 2</span>

                      <select name="myList">
                          <option value=""></option>
                          <option value="This">This</option>
                          <option value="That">That</option>
                          <option value="Other">Other</option>
                      </select>
                      <button id="btnEndStep2">NEXT STEP</button>
                  </div>
                  <div id="step3" class="hideMe"> <span>Finally, type something for Step 3</span>

                      <input type="textbox" />
                      <button id="btnEndStep3">END</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <ul id="progressbar">
                  <li class="active">1</li>
                  <li>2</li>
                  <li>3</li>
              </ul>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <button id="showModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#sampleModal">The Modal</button>
  ```

To see it in action - https://jsfiddle.net/32rL6gxk/23/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made the changes, You can look into the fiddle provided below :
https://jsfiddle.net/32rL6gxk/25/

```
$("#btnEndStep1").click(function () {
    $('ul').children().removeClass('active');
    $("#progressbar li").eq(1).addClass('active');
    $("#step1").addClass('hideMe');
    $("#step2").removeClass('hideMe');
});
$("#btnEndStep2").click(function () {
    $("#progressbar li").eq(1).removeClass('active');
    $("#progressbar li").eq(2).addClass('active');
    $("#step2").addClass('hideMe');
    $("#step3").removeClass('hideMe');
});
$("#btnEndStep3").click(function () {
    // Whatever your final validation and form submission requires
    $("#sampleModal").modal("hide");
});
```

Comment: I hope it helped !